# Automate deploying of synapse artifacts to devops repo

Tags: python-3.x, azure-synapse, azure-automation, azure-artifacts, azure-sdk-python

im trying to deploy some synapse artifacts to a synapse workspace with devops repo integration via a python runbook. By using the azure-synapse-artifacts library of the python azure sdk the artifacts are published directly to the live mode of the synapse workspace. Is there any way to deploy artifacts to a devops repo branch for synapse? Didnt find any devops repo apis or libaries, just for the direct integration of git.

Answer (score 0):

We can use CICD in this case, as this process will help to move entities from one environment to others, and for this we need to configure our synapse work space as source in GIT.

Below are few straight steps we can follow:

1. Set up Azure Synapse workspace and configure pipeline in Azure Devops.
2. Under staging while creating DevOps project, we can select Add Artifacts and select GIT.
3. Configure the workflow file and add workflow.

You can refer to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery) for detailed explanation of each step in achieving this task